# Desktop launcher won't launch the script

Tags: bash, launcher

I read about making desktop launchers [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Using_a_text_editor).

I have already successfully made some launchers for my little Python programs.

I have a program called Formreturn, for making and marking multiple choice forms. It is great, and nowadays free from github. (I paid $600 for it back then, but it was worth it for me.)

For some reason, after installing the latest version, the desktop icon does not install, I have to start it from bash:

```bsh
pedro@pedro-512ssd:~/Formreturn$ ./formreturn.sh
```

The program starts OK.

I spoke to Roland Quast, the author, about this, but he did not have a good solution. He blamed changes in Ubuntu.

So I thought I could make my own launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Version=1.0   
Name=Formreturn   
Comment=Multi-choice marking programme   
Exec=/home/pedro/Formreturn/formreturn.sh  
Icon=/home/pedro/icons/formreturn.png   
Terminal=false   
Type=Application  
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

I also tried with:

`Terminal=true`

But it does not launch!! Maybe because it is a bash script??

Any ideas what is wrong??

If you look at the attached picture, you will see what I see when I right click the launcher FR1. It has an extra tab "Open with".

If I right click my other home-made launchers, the ones for my Python programs, I don't see that, they just have 2 tabs: "Basic" and "Permissions"

Maybe this is some security feature??[image: right click the launcher then go to properties]

EDIT: This is formreturn.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash  

# (I commented this out with #) FRM_HOME=.    
FRM_HOME="/home/pedro/Formreturn/"
COMMAND_PATH=`echo ${0} | sed -e "s/\(.*\)\/.*$/\1/g"`
cd ${COMMAND_PATH}

if [ -z $JAVA_HOME ]; then
    JAVA_COMMAND=`which java`
    if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then
        echo "No executable java found. Please set JAVA_HOME variable."
        exit
    fi   
else
    JAVA_COMMAND=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
fi
if [ ! -x $JAVA_COMMAND ]; then
    echo "$JAVA_COMMAND is not executable. Please check the permissions."
    exit
fi
$JAVA_COMMAND -jar -Xmx1024m $FRM_HOME/lib/formreturn.jar "$1"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The program you are trying to run appears to be this [FormReturn](https://github.com/rquast/formreturn). If so, you likely need to edit [`formreturn.sh`](https://github.com/rquast/formreturn/blob/master/installer/linux/formreturn.sh) so that `FRM_HOME` points to the location of the script (likely `/home/pedro/Formreturn` – Note, *no* trailing slash).

  By default, it is set to `.` which won't work when the script is called from a launcher because the `pwd` may not be the same as the script location.
- Try recreating the desktop file from scratch. There may be something small that isn't right in the one you have. Like a trailing space that doesn't show up on the web.

  Also, make sure the `.desktop` file has the correct extension. Otherwise, it may be treated as an unknown filetype or ordinary text file.

Comment: My fault: I did not have the ending .desktop!! Stupid!! Now it works!! Sorry to have bothered you!

Comment: @Pedroski No problem. It happens. Glad it's working now. I'm going to clean up my comments since I think it's pretty much covered in my answer.